# Unexpected Token 'Import' issue in Jasmine, Protractor With Angular 2 Project with out angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I have created an Angular2 Project without using angular-cli. But while working with protractor when i am running my protractor.conf.js, its throwing error Unexpected token import(browser,element, by) from 'Protractor'.

I am using type script for test cases.

Following is the code for app.po.ts

```
import { browser, element, by, protractor } from 'protractor';
export class MainPage {
   navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getTitle() {
    return browser.getTitle();
  }

  getDasboardTitle() {
    return element(by.css('.al-title')).getText();
  }
}
```

Following is the code for app.ts

```
import { MainPage } from './app.po';
describe('demo-project App', function() {
  let page: MainPage ;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new MainPage ();
  });

  it('Application should have a title', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getTitle()).toEqual('Operator - Flight Operation Management');
  });

   it('Dasbord should have a heading', function() {
    expect(page.getTitle()).toEqual('DASHBOARD');
  });
});
```

And Following is the error while running the protractor

```
[11:45:08] E/launcher - Error: c:\Angular2\ui\src\protractor\app.ts:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { OperatorMainPage } from './app.po';
                                                              ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Node\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:71:5
    at Array.forEach (native) [11:45:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: What does app.ts and app.po.ts look like? I don't think the error is from the code included

Comment: i have added code for both file.

Comment: Maybe try `import { browser, element, by, protractor } from 'protractor/built';`. It helped me.

Comment: No that doesn't.. i think protractor is trying to run ts file without compiling it.  Do you have any idea how to configure build process for protractor.

Comment: Because you shouldn't run any .ts files. Before running your configuration file you should open cmd and in folder where you have your configuration you should write `tsc`. It will compile `.ts` to `.js`. Then you run conf.js. You should never run .ts files.

Comment: I know but is there any way do it automatically, like when i run protractor first it convert ts to js and run it. Like it happening in a project created through angular cli. In that we just need to write ng e2e and that run the protractor. Its protractor.conf.js also have ts file in specs.

Comment: I don't know if there is any way. There is probably some automation tool for it. You can write very simple .bat file where first you run `tsc` and then you run your protractor command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `MainPage` but calling `OperatorMainPage`. `OperatorMainPage` type does not exist.

```
import { MainPage } from './app.po';

describe('demo-project App', function() {
  let page: MainPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new MainPage();
  });

  it('Application should have a title', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getTitle()).toEqual('Operator - Flight Operation Management');
  });

   it('Dashbaord should have a heading', function() {
    expect(page.getTitle()).toEqual('DASHBOARD');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for having look, but that was not the issue.. its happens while copying. The main issue was my protractor.conf.js calling the app.ts but app.ts is not compiling to js.... that's why it didn't find import.

Comment: Huzzah! You could also use `ts-node` in your `onPrepare` to skip the step to transpile to JavaScript.

Comment: how to do this in onPrepare()?

Comment: Then you should explain your solution or link to the resource with this information.